# Isn't a possible to scroll a div *without* using jQuery (or other libraries)?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to scroll a div programmatically *without* using any libraries. Is it  possible and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at their source code, copy the relevant parts - it's not magic.

Comment: javascript is fine, but I don't want any additional libraries.

Comment: If it weren't possible, how would those libraries do it then?

Comment: Thank's everybody. Turned out that the problem wasn't the scrolling but me... (see correct answer below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('myEl');
myEl.scrollLeft = 12;
myEl.scrollTop = 34;
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but didn't work - just called it on the wrong div.... arrgh!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.Try this code.

```
<html>
<head><title>Scrolling a DIV with JavaScript</title>

<script language='javascript'>

  function move_up() {
    scroll_clipper.scrollTop = 0;
  }

</script>

</head>
<body>

  <a href='javascript:move_up()'>Move UP</a>

  <p>

  <div id='scroll_clipper' style='position:absolute; width:150px; height: 150px; overflow:auto'>
    <div id='scroll_text' style='background-color:yellow'>
       Here is some content that can be scrolled.
       <p>It uses two divs:<ul>
         <li>scroll_clipper, and
         <li>scroll_text
        </ul>

      scroll_clipper defines the scroll area while scroll_text
      defines the text to be scrolled.

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```