# Using CSS Grid, scroll a div from anywhere (w/out using jQuery plugins)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, scroll

How can the div, [`#scroll-content`](https://jsfiddle.net/blehmanade/x1k3rhj7/33/), be scrollable from anywhere on the page?

Currently, `#scroll-content` is scrollable only when the mouse is positioned over it; however, when the mouse is positioned on the div `#viz-container`, the `#scroll-content` div is not scrollable. So the goal is that when the user tries to scroll vertically independent of where the mouse is located on the page, the div `#scroll-content` should scroll.

Note the following:

1. answer should include the use of CSS Grid.
2. answer can include d3.v4
3. answer should NOT use jQuery (as is suggested in [answer0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262458/scroll-a-div-when-scroll-the-page))
4. answer should NOT use plugins (as is suggested in [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402766/scroll-a-div-from-everywhere) and in [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950185/jquery-scroll-a-divoverflowauto-with-a-div)).

Using `.scrollTop` as mentioned in [answer3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750851/isnt-a-possible-to-scroll-a-div-without-using-jquery-or-other-libraries) might be helpful, but this solution doesn't address the question asked here. We need to create a scroll event on a specific div whenever a vertical scroll event fires (independent of the mouse location during the vertical scroll event). We want to know how the div, [`#scroll-content`](https://jsfiddle.net/blehmanade/x1k3rhj7/33/), can be scrollable from anywhere on the page?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:hidden; /* stops scroll from the entire page */
  background-color: #ad6364;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% repeat(10,7%) 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% repeat(4,15%) 30% 5%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "int   int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int"
    "ftr   ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr";
  grid-gap:1px; 
}

#scroll-content {
  display:block;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  /*background-color:#ad6364;*/
  /*opacity: 0.75;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:#2B3033;
}
.step{
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  fill:#bdbdc1;
}

#viz-container{
  background-color:#2B3033;
  grid-area: viz1;
}
#nav-bar{
  grid-area:nav;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#side-bar1{
  grid-area:side1;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#side-bar2{
  grid-area:side2;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#footer{
  grid-area:ftr;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#interaction{
  grid-area:int;
  background-color:#767678;
}
.general-text{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color:#bdbdc1;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="nav-bar" class="general-text">nav</div>
      <div id="scroll-content" class="general-text">
        <section class="step">Question: how do we make this div #scroll-content scrollable from anywhere on the page? <br><br>Notice that if we place the mouse over this div, it's currently scrollable; however, if place the mouse over viz, then this div can not be scrolled. <br><br>...scroll down.
        </section>
        <section class="step">Note: none of the div positions are fixed b/c we're using CSS Grid.
         </section>
         <section class="step">...the end.
         </section>
      </div>
      <div id="viz-container" class="general-text">viz</div>
      <div id="interaction" class="general-text">interaction</div>
      <div id="side-bar1"></div>
      <div id="side-bar2"></div>
      <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wrote a very simple D3 answer which I just deleted, since I realized you want a *CSS grid* answer. In that case, it makes little sense to me including the D3 tag.

Comment: CSS grid is basically irrelevant to the question. Scrolling behavior is identical across grid, flex, and oldschool layouts.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado if you've got a simple D3 answer, undelete it -- I can't think of any way to do this other than reimplementing the jquery 'mousewheel'  plugin in vanilla, catching those events and using them to manually set the scrollTop of the content div.  (Which would be *sort* of reasonably doable; all the plugin does is reconcile the 'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', and 'MozMousePixelScroll' events into one handler...)

Comment: @blehman Well, that's what I did: I set a D3 event listener to the source div which changes the `scrollTop` of the target div. I see that that's not a solution for you. Let's see if someone else can help here.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - Seems pretty straightforward to use D3js with CSS Grid, but let's see your code. I explicitly mention that D3js can be used; I'd love to see your working example.

Comment: Ok, I just undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the selections with the two `<divs>` you have...

```
var viz = d3.select("#viz-container");
var scroll = d3.select("#scroll-content");
```

... probably the simplest solution is just setting the `scrollTop` of the target (the left hand one) based on an event in the source (the right hand one). This the whole code:

```
viz.on("wheel", function() {
    scroll.property("scrollTop", +scroll.property("scrollTop") + d3.event.deltaY)
});
```

Here is your code with that change only (click "full page"):

```js
var viz = d3.select("#viz-container");
var scroll = d3.select("#scroll-content");
viz.on("wheel", function() {
  scroll.property("scrollTop", +scroll.property("scrollTop") + d3.event.deltaY)
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:hidden; /* stops scroll from the entire page */
  background-color: #ad6364;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height:100%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% repeat(10,7%) 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% repeat(4,15%) 30% 5%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "side1 side1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 viz1 side2"
    "int   int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int  int"
    "ftr   ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr  ftr";
  grid-gap:1px; 
}

#scroll-content {
  display:block;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2 / 6;
  /*background-color:#ad6364;*/
  /*opacity: 0.75;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:#2B3033;
}
.step{
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  fill:#bdbdc1;
}

#viz-container{
  background-color:#2B3033;
  grid-area: viz1;
}
#nav-bar{
  grid-area:nav;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#side-bar1{
  grid-area:side1;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#side-bar2{
  grid-area:side2;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#footer{
  grid-area:ftr;
  background-color:#767678;
}
#interaction{
  grid-area:int;
  background-color:#767678;
}
.general-text{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color:#bdbdc1;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="nav-bar" class="general-text">nav</div>
      <div id="scroll-content" class="general-text">
        <section class="step">Question: how do we make this div #scroll-content scrollable from anywhere on the page? <br><br>Notice that if we place the mouse over this div, it's currently scrollable; however, if place the mouse over viz, then this div can not be scrolled. <br><br>...scroll down.
        </section>
        <section class="step">Note: none of the div positions are fixed b/c we're using CSS Grid.
         </section>
         <section class="step">...the end.
         </section>
      </div>
      <div id="viz-container" class="general-text">viz</div>
      <div id="interaction" class="general-text">interaction</div>
      <div id="side-bar1"></div>
      <div id="side-bar2"></div>
      <div id="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: I'm using `deltaY` but you can use another value, making the scroll smoother.

Comment: would you expect this solution to work on an iphone?

Comment: note: I added a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49455765/specifically-on-mobile-scroll-a-div-from-anywhere-w-out-using-jquery-plugins) specifically for mobile.